# MAC based routing with nftables and ipv6

Tags: ipv6, nftables, mac-address

I want to match every traffic from a server but it is at the same interface.

```
MAC 88:7e:25:d3:90:0b > ens19 > table 147
```

Therefore I made this `nftables` rule

```
table ip filter { # handle 3
    chain input { # handle 1
            type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
            iif "ens19" ether saddr 88:7e:25:d3:90:0b meta mark set 0x00000093 # handle 2
            iif "ens19" ether saddr 08:05:e2:04:ce:b3 meta mark set 0x00003417 # handle 3
    }
```

}

And ip rule for specify routing table

```
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x93 lookup 147
ip rule add from all fwmark 13335 lookup 147
ip -6 rule add from all fwmark 0x93 lookup 147
ip -6 rule add from all fwmark 13335 lookup 147
```

[image: tshark info]

But I use `tshark` to see if it works, it shows there is no incoming packages and I can't ping the address. So something is wrong with matching income flow.

And if I use

```
 from all iif ens19 lookup 147
```

instead of

```
ip -6 rule add from all fwmark 0x93 lookup 147
ip -6 rule add from all fwmark 13335 lookup 147
```

it works, so it must be something wrong with my `nftables` rules.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: see where the routing decision is done    https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook input` is specifically meant for packets where the local host is the final destination – it is only reached *after* routing decisions have been made, as that's how netfilter knows which packets are processed through "hook input" chains and which ones go through "hook forward" chains. So at that point, your policy rules no longer matter.

Instead, I think you need `hook prerouting` (and probably with `priority raw`?).

Comment: Thanks for the awser,afther I changed it to `chain prerouting {
               type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;` it works